# How can I combine PCollections while still retaining the TaggedOutputs?

Tags: apache-beam

I am creating a package specific to my company's pipelines and use cases to simplify future Apache Beam (Dataflow) pipelines. One key thing I want to manage is capturing and redirection of failures.

I have several `PTransform`s that will be working with `TaggedOutput`s. There are times when I will want to combine them, but still keep the `TaggedOutput`s.

Sometimes this is do-able, if there is just one `TaggedOutput`, but sometimes what I am flattening has multiple tags.

Let me explain via example. In a `PTransform`, I have the following code, where I can manage the tags with no problem:

```py
        fails = []
        for timestamp_field in self.timestamp_fields:
            output, fail = output | f'Convert "{timestamp_field}"' >> ParDo(
                ConvertTimestamp(self.fail_tag), timestamp_field
            ).with_outputs(self.fail_tag, main=self.success_tag)  # type: ignore
            fails.append(fail)
        fails = (
            fails
            | "Flatten all timestamp fails" >> Flatten()
            | Map(lambda elem: pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.fail_tag, elem))
        )
```

In this case, I can flatten the list of fails that are generated, then apply the tag that they had again.

But then later on, I want this `PTransform` to be able to return different types of tags. Specifically, in this case, I want to return both the good output and the bad output.  They have been separated by having different tags.  How can I combine them, but keep the tags?

```py
        result = (
            (
                output,
                fails,
            )
            | "Flatten output and errors" >> Flatten()
        )
        return result
```

In this case, `result` will be returned with all of the tags lost: `Flatten()` will remove them. And I cannot do something like I did above, since I will have different tags that I want to apply.

---

#### Is there a way to combine `PCollections` without losing the tags?

#### Is there a way to add a tag to a `PTransform`?

(If there were a way to do something like `with_outputs` on a `PTransform`, this would also allow me to restructure my code to manage the tags.)

#### Is there a way that I can return the result and make the fails *distinguishable* from the good output?

I'm using output tags.  Maybe there is another way, if I cannot get tags to work.

---

I'm using Python for all of my work, but if you're better with Java and can explain better with that, I can rework a Java solution into my Python work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve.

```
import apache_beam as beam

POSITIVE_TAG = "positive"
NEGATIVE_TAG = "negative"


class SplitMessages(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        from apache_beam.pvalue import TaggedOutput

        if element > 0:
            yield TaggedOutput(POSITIVE_TAG, element)
        else:
            yield TaggedOutput(NEGATIVE_TAG, element)


with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    data = p | "test" >> beam.Create([1, 2, 3, -3, 1, -4])
    pp = data | beam.ParDo(SplitMessages()).with_outputs(POSITIVE_TAG, NEGATIVE_TAG)
    # put them back
    p3 = (pp[POSITIVE_TAG], pp[NEGATIVE_TAG]) | beam.Flatten()
    # you can still access other Pcollections
    pp[NEGATIVE_TAG] | beam.Map(print)
    p3 | "print all " >> beam.Map(print)
```

If you look at this example, you can always access any PCollections.

Comment: Thanks!  Let me try to incorporate to see if it is doing what I want.  If so, I will accept.